# Java Swings JMenuBar is not visible in windows 8

Tags: windows-8, jmenubar

One of my application which is working fine since a long time, recently I installed it on Windows 8 and I saw that complete JMenuBar is not visible there anyone have any solution for this.

regards
Rajeev

Answer (score 0):

solved myslef, there were some issue related to OS version check.
thanks